# Python で Rainbow カラーマップをグレースケール変換

Tags: python, matplotlib, matlab

Rainbow カラーマップで保存された jpeg イメージを Python で読み込んで、カラーマップに従ってグレースケールする方法はないでしょうか。
通常 256 色で表現されるカラーマップの RGB 値を、マップの順位に従って、 0 から 255 の数字に対応させたいのですが、普通にグレースケールするとカラーマップの中央付近に最大値が来てしまいます (https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html)。

MATLAB を用いた方法 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440340/jet-colormap-to-grayscale) を見つけましたが、当方 MATLAB に詳しくないため、両方に明るい方がいらっしゃいましたら、Python で同じことをするにはどうすればよいかご教示ください。
リンク先 *rgb2ind* という関数 (?) と同じ機能が Python のモジュールにあると嬉しいのですが。

その他、なにかお考えをお持ちの方ございましたら是非ご教示くださいませ。

Comment: 先達が居たようです。答えも出ています。[How I can specify how rainbow color scheme should be converted to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343981/how-i-can-specify-how-rainbow-color-scheme-should-be-converted-to-grayscale)

Comment: @kunif さん、重要な情報ありがとうございます！　よければ本家 Stack Overflow の回答を元にご回答頂けませんか？　Stack Overflow 上の回答はクリエイティブコモンズでライセンスされているので、回答者へのリンクと回答へのリンクを含めていれば単に翻訳するだけでも投稿できます :) 詳しくは[「質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261/19110)をご覧ください<(_ _)>

Answer (score 1):

コメントでの提言により、以下記事の内容を(そのままではなく)かいつまんで翻訳・転記します。
[How I can specify how rainbow color scheme should be converted to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343981/how-i-can-specify-how-rainbow-color-scheme-should-be-converted-to-grayscale)
元記事の質問画像に関するコメント等は後ろに別途まとめました。

---

- 元々の画像を作成した際に使われたカラーマップが何か知っていることを前提にしています。
- 以下の記事の回答に示したコードの一部を使っています。
   [How to decode color mapping in matplotlib's Colormap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177154/how-to-decode-color-mapping-in-matplotlibs-colormap)
- カラーマップは(RAINBOWではなく) JETだと仮定します。

元記事回答からのコードコピー(ただし転記者は未検証です)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread("data/jetcolimage.png")
print image.shape, image.max()

r = np.linspace(0,1, 256)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(0,1)
cmap = plt.cm.jet
mapvals = cmap(norm(r))[:,:3]

def get_value_from_cm(color):
    color=matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(color)
    #if color is already gray scale, dont change it
    if np.std(color) < 0.1:
        return np.mean(color)
    #otherwise return value from colormap
    distance = np.sum((mapvals - color)**2, axis=1)
    return r[np.argmin(distance)]

newim = np.zeros_like(image)
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        c = image[i,j,:3]
        newim[i,j] =  get_value_from_cm(c)


fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax.imshow(image)
ax2.imshow(newim, cmap="gray")

ax.axis("off")
ax2.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

---

元記事の質問画像はカラーマップ画像以外(黒の枠線や数字と元から灰色)の要素を含んでいます。
単純なカラーマップ画像以外を処理する場合には、グレースケールにもカラーマップにも属さない値を扱う必要があるそうです。
画像のアンチエイリアシング処理が原因で白が表示されることがあるらしいとか。

以下の記事回答中で「(画像を)あるカラーマップから別のカラーマップに変更する方法」として、それらグレースケールにもカラーマップにも属さない値を、最も近い値に変換する処理を扱っているようです。
[How can I change colors in contours (obtained from non-Python) with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478981/how-can-i-change-colors-in-contours-obtained-from-non-python-with-python/51484647#51484647)

Comment: スクリプトが動作することを確認しました。Python 3 で動かすには `print` のところだけを修正すれば良かったです。また、`cmap = plt.cm.jet` の部分を変更すれば jet 以外にも対応できそうです。